# Method for returning row with mysql that matches both values through a relational join

Tags: mysql

I have data connected over three tables in mysql and I'm looking for a method to return rows that match all values passed to the MYSQL query. For example, imagine a "people" table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Steve |
|  2 | Oli   |
|  3 | Mike  |
+----+-------+
```

And then I have a movies table:

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |         Film         |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Life Aquatic         |
|  2 | Grand Budapest Hotel |
|  3 | Fantastic Mr Fox     |
+----+----------------------+
```

And people's favourite movies are connected through a third table:

```
+----------+-----------+
| person_id| movie_id  |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 |         1 |
|        1 |         2 |
|        2 |         1 |
|        3 |         2 |
+----------+-----------+
```

What's the quickest way to query the database returning people that like "life aquatic" AND "Grand Budapest Hotel"? In this case it should indeed just return "Steve". I have started building up a query that performs a subquery counting the rows it returns but it feels very large and clunky for something seemingly so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` query with `group by` clause to get the required names, e.g:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM person p JOIN person_movie pm ON p.id = pm.person_id
JOIN movie m ON pm.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.name in ('Life Aquatic', 'Grand Budapest Hotel')
group by p.name
having count(m.name) >= 2;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a078/6/0)**.

Comment: Nice idea: upvoting the fiddle

Comment: Great! This feels quite neat. Thanks for the fiddle

Answer (score 3):

You can start by joining people against the films they like as you normally would:

```
SELECT person.name
FROM person
JOIN person_movie ON (person.id = person_id)
JOIN movies ON (movies.id = movie_id)
WHERE movies.film IN ('Life Aquatic', 'Grand Budapest Hotel');
```

This will return Steve *twice*, and Oli and Mike once each.

And you know that you have *two* records to look for. So:

```
SELECT person.name /*, COUNT(*) AS hits */
FROM person
JOIN person_movie ON (person.id = person_id)
JOIN movies ON (movies.id = movie_id)
WHERE movies.film IN ('Life Aquatic', 'Grand Budapest Hotel')
GROUP BY person.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

will restrict the list to one entry for Steve.

This also allows you to select those people with, say, three films out of four (pass four titles in the WHERE, and restrict to `COUNT(*) >= 3`).

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no "simple and clean" solution to this requirement. You want an intersection. Checkout [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php) various techniques for intersections; you will see that all of them are a little clunky.

I personally prefer this way:

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE id IN (SELECT person_id 
             FROM favourite_movies
             WHERE movie_id = 1
             )
AND id IN (SELECT person_id 
             FROM favourite_movies
             WHERE movie_id = 2
             )
```